Dropdown search using a combobox in a JSP, MYSQL Java Web Project on Apache Netbeans
So far I could make a form which contains a combobox which successfully brings from the DB a list of users from a table as options to choose in a combobox. However, I was asked to add a search section in that combobox to filter among all those results to choose one. I'm not sure if this is capable to be used in a Java Web project (Jakarta EE 10 on Apache Netbeans). I'm not sure if I will need to import a library or dependency on my project. Any suggestions on how to approach this?
Remember that I'm not asking how to populate a combobox with the options comming from the DB but I want to add a search filter to filter among those results from that combobox.
<!--THE COMBOBOX WITH OPTIONS FILLED FROM THE DATABASE--->
              <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="idUsuario" class="form-label">Usuario</label>
                    <select class="form-select" id="idUsuario" name="idUsuario" required>
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccionar Usuario</option>
                        <% 
                            PreparedStatement psUsuarios2 = con.prepareStatement("SELECT IdUsuario, Nombres FROM Usuario WHERE EstadoRegistro = 1");
                            ResultSet rsUsuarios2 = psUsuarios2.executeQuery();
                            while (rsUsuarios2.next()) {
                        %>
                        <option value="<%= rsUsuarios2.getInt("IdUsuario") %>"><%= rsUsuarios2.getString("Nombres") %></option>
                        <% } rsUsuarios2.close(); psUsuarios2.close(); %>
                    </select>
                </div>

I am expecting to let the user search among the results brought from the BD inside the combobox

JSP is in the context of this question merely a HTML code generator. Next time you face this kind of problem, take a step back and try researching how to achieve it in plain HTML. Once figured out, just adjust JSP code in such way that it produces exactly the desired HTML. See abovelinked duplicate.

Once you create a filter and add it to the JSP you should modify your query to include additional conditions defined by the filter, and then submit it to the server to adjust the results. If you want to write a filter directly to JSP file then make sure the combobox is repopulated upon changes in the filter. You can also create a filter API to save it in the DB, and retrieve it along with JSP page to keep the state of the data returned.
